# Huawei. Obtain data(title, body, sentTime) from notification by using Push Kit. Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-push-notification

Im trying obtain data from notification, when my app is closed and when app is just in background. I get notification, tap on it, and in MainActivity(from android project) i want to obtain data.
I can do it when my app is open, by HmsMessageService and OnMessageReceived, there is no problem. But i cant find examples, how to do it when app is closed. Any help, pls.
There is my notification in Json:

```
        var jObject = new
        {
            message = new
            {
                notification = new
                {
                    title = titleNot,
                    body = bodyNot
                },
                android = new
                {
                    notification = new
                    {
                        foreground_show = false,
                        click_action = new
                        {
                            type = 3
                        }
                    }
                },
                token = new[] { token }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

When the application is closed, you can obtain parameters by customizing `click_action`.

Set **intent** in the message body on your app server.

```
{
    "message": {
        "notification": {
            "title": "message title",
            "body": "message body"
        },
        "android": {
            "notification": {
                "click_action": {
                    "type": 1,
                    "intent": "intent://com.huawei.xahmspushdemo/deeplink?#Intent;scheme=pushscheme;launchFlags=0x4000000;i.age=180;S.name=abc;end"
                }
            }
        },
        "token": [
            "pushtoken1"
        ]
    }
}
```

This is the [document](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/xamarin-customizingactions-0000001055648851).

Comment: i hoped that should be a simplier way to do it. without changing message Type. Google Firebase allow to do it, Unfortunately Hms is not.

Comment: In my opinion, In this mode, the message type is not changed. just added the intent parameter and the parameter is transferred through the intent .

Answer (score 2):

Just as what Np0v0 mentioned, you can use click_action to get the data. There is another way to implement the goal.

1. Register an Activity class to be started in the AndroidManifest.xml file of the app.

[image]

[image]

3.Receive data using the customized activity class.

For more detail information, pls refer to https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/andorid-basic-clickaction-0000001087554076#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001087554076__li7205195217309

Answer (score 1):

Solved problem without changing "`click_action` type". Just override `OnNewIntent`() method in main activity, and add "`GetIntentData`" with some logic.

```
    private void GetIntentData(Bundle bNotification)
    {
        if (bNotification != null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (bNotification.ContainsKey(TITLE_KEY) && bNotification.ContainsKey(BODY_KEY))
                {
                    \\...
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }
    protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);
        GetIntentData(intent?.Extras);
    }
```

in `OnCreate`() I created bundle and if its not null I load app:

```
        Bundle bNotification = Intent.Extras;
        if (bNotification == null || bNotification.IsEmpty)
        {
            LoadApplication(new App(...));
        }
        else
        {
            LoadApplication(new App(true, ...));
            GetIntentData(bNotification);
        }
```

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/xamarin-customizingactions-0000001055648851